# How to redirect to another page if referrer url is not a specific url in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm using WordPress with Elementor, I want a certain page to be accessible only if it comes from a certain url. I saw from other answers in similar questions that I can use this:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse15677455_redirect' );

function wpse15677455_redirect() {

  $value = ('https://mywebsite.com/quotaton/') ;
    if (!is_page(555) & wp_get_referer() !== $value ) {

       wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );

    }
 };
```

I tried using this in the function.php of the theme but it returns the error "Unable to communicate with server to check for fatal errors". I tried with all plugins deactivated except elementor but same result.
I tried without the add_action call but, despite not giving errors, it also does nothing. I can't seem to find the right place/way to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_redirects() {
 
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/dashboard/' ) );
        die;
    }
 
    if ( is_page('contact') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/new-contact/' ) );
        die;
    }
 
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_redirects' );
```

is_page('contact') => 'contact' is page slug.
is_page(150) => '150' is page ID.

Comment: Can you explain the second if? What is 'contact'? Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: 'contact' is page slug.

Answer (score 0):

Trying out the code, I believe the problem is that you're missing a single ampersand(&) for the `And` operator. Also, if `is_page` is used to check for the "certain page", maybe the `not`(!) operator isn't necessary...

```php
if (is_page(555) && wp_get_referer() !== $value ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If the link that has to be redirected comes from a page, you could use a redirection plugin like this one: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/

Once activated you just edit the page you want to be redirected inserting the correct link in the page links to field.